# Spark - behaviour of first() operation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to understand the jobs that get created by Spark for simple first() vs collect() operations.

Given the code:

```
myRDD = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(['A', 'B', 'C'])

def func(d):
    return d + '-foo'

myRDD = myRDD.map(func)
```

My RDD is split across 16 partitions:

```
print(myRDD.toDebugString())
(16) PythonRDD[24] at RDD at PythonRDD.scala:48 []
 |   ParallelCollectionRDD[23] at parallelize at PythonRDD.scala:475 []
```

If I call:

```
myRDD.collect()
```

I get 1 job with 16 tasks created. I assume this is one task per partition.

However, if I call:

```
myRDD.first()
```

I get 3 jobs, with 1, 4, and 11 tasks created. Why have 3 jobs been created?

I'm running spark-2.0.1 with a single 16-core executor, provisioned by Mesos.

Comment: Could you also mention spark version and your cluster setup.

Comment: @shanmuga updated, thanks

Comment: AFAIK collect() actually causes a shuffle into 1 partition. it could be that first() is being run across 3 partitions. *shrug*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually pretty smart Spark behaviour. Your `map()` is transformation (it is lazy-evaluated) and both `first()` and `collect()` are actions (terminal operations). All transformations are applied to the data in time you call actions.

When you call `first()` then spark tries to perform as low number of operations (transformations) as possible. First, it tries one random partition. If there are no results, it takes 4 times partitions more and calculates. Again, if there are no results, spark takes 4 times partitions more (5 * 4) and again tries to get any result.

In your case in this third try you have only 11 untouched partitions (16 - 1 - 4). If you have more data in RDD or less number of partitions, spark probably can find the `first()` result sooner.

Comment: Does first() bring all the data to the driver like collect?

Comment: @user2441441 It brings only one record to the driver - the first record found in the DF/RDD.

Comment: Yes, but sice I will have a filter before is, if there is no row with that filter, will it go though all the rows to find the first() and then not find it? SO in essence everything will come to the driver?

Comment: For me first() is causing a Stack Overflow error

Comment: If there is only one row in the DF matching the applied transformations, you're right, entire DF (of size 1) will be loaded to the driver

Comment: So if I understood it, when using df.filter().first(), will it bring entire dataframe to driver and them do the filter, or do the filter in the mappers and then only collect the first() to the driver? Thank you!

Comment: df is of size 1 million rows

Comment: @user2441441 It will apply filters in the executors, only one (matching) row will be transferred to the driver.